# Resharper doesn't display summary for jqeury.intellisense.js

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2012, resharper

When I use visual studio intellisence the summary for jquery method displays well and I can easily choose between overload methods.  But when I use resharper intellisense, the summary is not displaying . Did anybody face this problem or have any idea how to make resharper display summary for jquery.intellisense?

[image: Visual Studio Intellisense]

[image: Resharper Intellisense]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

visual studio reads xml comments and embed them in the intellisence but resharper only read the summary part from the xml comments and when there is param tags in the comment resharper doesn't read it  , by the way jquery-vsdoc.js is a better alternative to jquery.intellisence.js

Answer (score 0):

Answer from user1239169 is not correct. In fact, ReSharper doesn't support "intellisense.annotate" style commonly used in "*.intellisense.js" files as of 8.1 and in previous versions. In other cases (such as with "*vsdoc.js") it parses everything (summary, params, signature tags), at least in 8.1 version.